# Execution rights on downloaded file

Tags: php, linux

I have a PHP website that lets users download an installer for an application. The installer is a self extracting archive packaged into a single .sh file.

The PHP to initiate the download is as so:

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$name);
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');       
readfile('bin/' . $name);
```

where *$name* is the name of the sh file.

The file has execution rights on the web server but they are lost once the file is downloaded. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. HTTP has no means to describe expected file permissions (which work in different ways on different platforms anyway).

Comment: @schmop Yes, thats all about his operating system and his settings